Verification of a demonstration
I need to know if the proof I made for the following problem is correct.
Problem: If C is a matrix of order $3 \times 3$ such that $\text{rank}(C) = 2$, then $\text{det}(C) = 0$
Proof: If it must be shown that the determinant of C is $0$, we could show that C does not have an inverse, since every matrix that does not have an inverse has $0$ as its determinant. For this we can use the following theorem: $A$ is a matrix of order $n \times n$ is a matrix that has an inverse $\leftrightarrow \text{ran}(A) = n$
In our case: $C$ is an invertible matrix $\leftrightarrow \text{ran}(C) = 3$
But $\text{rank}(C) = 2 \neq 3$, therefore, $C$ has no inverse, which means $\text{det}(C) = 0$

Your argument is correct.

Thanks for the feedback

Please, use descriptive titles. "Verification of a demonstration" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Welcome to the site :) FYI your question is not considered in line with the websites guidelines --->  "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
Keep this in my mind for your next post.

A $3 \times 3$ matrix with rank 2 means only two columns are independent. Therefore the third column can be written as a linear combination of the other two and reduced to zero. So the determinant must be zero.

Thanks, I will take the questions into account. Responding to the other, I also had this way of demonstrating it in mind, since having a range of 2, it was clear that it would have a row full of zeros, if so, its determinant would be 0
